# Which pattern design can implement on this request on NestJs

Tags: typescript, design-patterns, nestjs, factory

I have a controller with with two queries engine: which defines the engine to use(i have 6 at the moment) and q: which is the term of search.

```
    if (query.engine == 'nytimes') {
      return this.nytimesService.search(query.q);
    }
    if (query.engine == 'theguardian') {
      return this.theguardianService.search(query.q);
    }
    if (query.engine == 'catcher') {
      return this.newscatcherService.search(query.q);
    }
    if (query.engine == 'newsapi') {
      return this.newsapiService.search(query.q);
    }
    if (query.engine == 'newsdata') {
      return this.newsdataService.search(query.q);
    }
    if (!req.user?.id) {
      return 'To search on all engines should be authenticated';
    } else if (query.engine == 'any') {
      return this.summarizeService.search(query.q);
    }
    return 'Unknown engine'
```

In the controller, depending on the engine, I call the corresponding service and then call the search method. On services, the logic is defined to make the request to the api (theguardian, nytimes, ...) and normalize the data within it.

```
@Injectable()
export class TheGuardianService {
  constructor(
    private readonly httpService: HttpService,
    private readonly configService: ConfigService,
  ) {}

  private buildUrl(termOfSearch: string) {
    const apiKey = this.configService.get<string>('THEGUARDIAN_API_KEY');
    const base = this.configService.get('THEGUARDIAN_API_URL');
    return base + `&api-key=${apiKey}` + `&q=${termOfSearch}`;
  }

  search(termOfSearch: string): Observable<{ data: Observable<News[]> }> {
    const url = this.buildUrl(termOfSearch);
    return this.httpService.get(url).pipe(
      map((res) => {
        const { response } = res.data;
        if (response.results.length == 0) {
          throw new NotFoundException('TheGuardian Service: News not found');
        }
        return {
          engine: 'The Guardian Api',
          total_news: response.pageSize,
          data: response.results.map(
            (element) =>
              new News(
                element.webUrl,
                element.webTitle,
                element.webPublicationDate,
              ),
          ),
        };
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow ! Can you precise what is the question exactly ? You showed your code, explained what it does but didn't explained precisely what you are looking for.